# Cowboy as a reverse proxy to Apache

Tags: apache, erlang, reverse-proxy, cowboy

I wanna use Erlang Cowboy server as a reverse proxy to Apache server but I can't find any information where to start. Cowboy documentation very modest also there isn't many information about Cowboy in Google. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want to do that? Cowboy is more of a server framework than an out of the box application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a reverse proxy module for cowboy using a http client library like [gun](https://github.com/ninenines/gun) from the same developer as cowboy.

Another option is with [yaws server](http://yaws.hyber.org/) as revproxy. You can read the instructions on [man page](http://hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf):

> revproxy = Prefix Url [intercept_mod Module]
>                 Make  Yaws a reverse proxy. Prefix is a path inside our own doc-
>                 root and Url argument is a URL pointing to a website we want  to
>                 "mount" under the Prefix path.

Regards